# MySQL dropping table on which transaction happening

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm facing the following strange issue, plz help me to resolve it.

FYI, im using MySQL server 5.5 and innodb engine.

1. Open two mysql client sessions in two different console windows
2. In first session, 
   -> create table XYZ and insert some data
   -> start transaction
   -> update table set somecolumn = somevalue
3. In other session,
   -> drop table XYZ

Its dropping table on which transaction is happening. I tried autocommit=off too.but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

that's not so strange.

you start the transaction after you create the table, which means it's fair game for the other session

what do you expect to happen?

perhaps you want to start the transaction before creating the table?

or you could try issue a [lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html) on the table manually

Comment: Even before i close transaction, how could mysql allow drop table XYZ?

Comment: because mysql transactions and table locks suck. http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-transaction-gotchas-good-parts/